# Building gstreamer-sharp glue on Windows

Tags: gstreamer

I want to upgrade my Windows WPF C# application to use GStreamer 1.4 instead of GStreamer 0.10.
I built gstreamer-sharp on Linux without any errors, the dll size is 1.24 MB which seems reasonable and when I reference gstreamer-sharp.dll from my C# application, all class and method names which I'm using are resolved.  Good.

I have a problem building the glue on Windows though. I took a Visual Studio project template from gstreamer-sharp, changed the output from application to library, added gobject.c and generated.c from gstreamer-sharp to the project, added a path to WinDDK to resolve msvcrt_winxp.obj and I built libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll, whose size is 50.5 kB (seems pretty small, shouldn't it be 3 times as big?).
When I try to use it with a C# application, I get an error when calling Gst.Application.InitCheck(ref args):

> Unable to find an entry point named 'gst_value_list_get_type' in DLL 'libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll'

No wonder it complains, such a method does not exist in generated.c.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gstreamer-sharp is not using the glue library for all the calls to the native side. The glue library is only used for accessing fields from GObjects and Opaque types. The glue library is just returning the padding of the field to calculate the offset of the field on the managed side. The glue size seems fine, since it's just a small wrapper to calculate the offsets.
The error is more likely to be caused when using the Application class, as it initializes all the GstValue types on access. Maybe the windows binaries are broken and do not contain gst_value_list_get_type which would be weird though. Can you try writing a small C Program which calls that function to see if you get any errors. If the C program works fine then .NET can probably not find your libraries, though you would usually get a DllNotFoundException in this case.

You can find a repository with a visual studio project for the glue here https://github.com/xDarkice/libgstreamersharpglue

Comment: I'm back to GStreamer after being distracted by another project.  The binaries were OK, gstreamersharp was OK, it was the glue which was wrong.  Sebastian sent me a link to your VS2013 libgstreamersharpglue project, I built the glue on my machine and everything started to work!  If you edit your answer and publish the link to your repository, I'll mark it as correct.  Thank you very much for making that project public, it solved all of my problems, there must have been something wrong with my VS2010 glue solution.